# Apollo Server 3 with graphql-ws middleware subscriptions

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, graphql, apollo-server

I am newbie to graphql and trying to create a middleware with apollo graphql server 3 and graphql-ws. The query and mutation are working fine but there a lot of issues with subscription. The official documentation of graphql state that it is better to work with `graphql-ws` instead of `subscriptions-transport-ws`.

Subscription is working fine with nodejs but when tried to a Java project especifically with webflux doesn't. For test the API i am using Altair and the websocket seem like is connected but from server there are some logs that are contradictory.

**Middleware Nodejs** :
https://github.com/kamboj652/graphql-middleware

**Nodejs Server** :
https://github.com/kamboj652/nodejs-graphql-server

**Spring Boot Server** :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/tree/main/samples --> webflux-websocket

**Edit**

The idea behind the question is this. I think a picture speaks more than 1000 words.
[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to start an Apollo 3 GraphQL server that uses graphql-ws websockets for subscriptions and consume it with Apollo Client? This is what I finally managed to get up and running yesterday.

Comment: I updated the post with a picture.

Comment: Thank's for the picture, this clarifies a lot.
So you want to expose the apis of all Backend GraphQL-Services as one single GraphQL API? Did you have a look at Apollo Federation, that seems to be what you're trying to build by youself.
In the Apollo-Server subscription docs they say that Federation does not support subscriptions, but there's an interesting article by them that shows an interesting alternative /  "workaround":
https://www.apollographql.com/blog/backend/federation/using-subscriptions-with-your-federated-data-graph/